# Sorting out Chrome-related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-request, clean-up

Someone's muddled the chrome-related tags!

*Chromium* is an open-source web browser.  *Chrome* is a closed-source derivative of Chromium made by Google.  *Chrome OS* is an operating system based on the same closed Google browser.  *Chromium OS*, however, is the operating system based directly on the open-source Chromium.

As of now, there are three tags: [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [chromium](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromium), and [chrome-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chrome-os).  This is misleading because:

Google's *Chrome OS* is ONLY available when it comes pre-installed on a Chromebook.

The "Chrome OS" that people try to install on their previously-bought laptops (nightly builds, etc.) **is not** Chrome OS.  It is **actually Chromium OS**.  This fosters many more questions about compiling, installing, etc. than the pre-built, pre-installed, pre-configured Chrome OS.

We should revise these tags to be [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [google-chrome-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-os), either [chromium](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromium) or [chromium-browser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromium-browser) (to make it clear to unknowledgable people), and [chromium-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromium-os).

<s>There also exists a [chromeos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromeos) tag, which should be merged into [chrome-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chrome-os). (We can leave extensions as one tag as I believe they are cross-compatible.)</s>

Comment: After all of those "chrome"s, it's starting to not even look like a word anymore!

Comment: doesn't help that [chromium-os] is a synonym of [google-chrome-os], so the questions can't be retagged appropriately

Comment: Oh no!  That's even worse.

Comment: Are there any updates on this?  Is anybody working on it?  (Just trying to bring it back to the foreground for a bit.)

Comment: @slhck I'd like to see an update on this too. I think it's pretty important.

Comment: I agree [chromium-browser] would probably be better than [chromium]. I would also make [google-chrome] a synonym of [chromium], as most questions there are about the base Chromium features rather than Google Chrome peculiarities, but I'd also understand if the opposite happened. :)